# Creating a tree template in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, tree

I am working with a database used to store information about entities in the form of a tree of components. For example, it might have a camry object with children air-conditioner and engine. The engine might have pistons as children, and air-con have vents as children.

The idea is that the user would custom-create something like this as a 'template' which would then be used to instantiate the camry 'tree' as needed. So the user might first create the template, and then use it to add ten of those camry trees to a workshop, storing unique data against each by selecting 'add new car', selecting camry, and then picking a name.

How would you store such a construction in a database, and is there any easy way to instantiate a tree like that?

Comment: when you say "template" what exactly do you mean? Do you mean that a template would be generic (IE Air conditioner, then vent) and that the copy would be specific -- "model number x air conditioner" and "model x vent" ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've done the first half of this before, so we'll start there (convenient, no?). Without knowing to much about your needs I'd recommend the following as a base (you can adjust the column widths as needed):

```
CREATE TABLE tree (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY (parent_id, type, name),
    KEY (parent_id)
);
```

Why did I do it this way? Well, let's go through each field. `id` is a globally unique value that we can use to identify this element and all the elements that directly depend on it. `parent_id` lets us go back up through the tree until we reach `parent_id == 0`, which is the top of the tree. `type` would be your "car" or "vent" descriptions. `name` would let you qualify `type`, so things like "Camry" and "Driver Left" (for "vent" obviously).

The data would be stored with values like these:

```
INSERT INTO tree (parent_id, type, name) VALUES
    (0, 'car', 'Camry'),
    (1, 'hvac', 'HVAC'),
    (2, 'vent', 'Driver Front Footwell'),
    (2, 'vent', 'Passenger Front Footwell'),
    (2, 'vent', 'Driver Rear Footwell'),
    (2, 'vent', 'Passenger Rear Footwell'),
    (1, 'glass', 'Glass'),
    (7, 'window', 'Windshield'),
    (7, 'window', 'Rear Window'),
    (7, 'window', 'Driver Front Window'),
    (7, 'window', 'Passenger Front Window'),
    (7, 'window', 'Driver Rear Window'),
    (7, 'window', 'Passenger Rear Window'),
    (1, 'mirrors', 'Mirrors'),
    (14, 'mirror', 'Rearview Mirror'),
    (14, 'mirror', 'Driver Mirror'),
    (14, 'mirror', 'Passenger Mirror');
```

I could keep going, but I think you get the idea. Just to be sure though... All those values would result in a tree that looked like this:

```
(1, 0, 'car', 'Camry')
  |  (2, 1, 'hvac', 'HVAC')
  |    +- (3, 2, 'vent', 'Driver Front Footwell')
  |    +- (4, 2, 'vent', 'Passenger Front Footwell')
  |    +- (5, 2, 'vent', 'Driver Rear Footwell')
  |    +- (6, 2, 'vent', 'Passenger Rear Footwell')
  +- (7, 1, 'glass', 'Glass')
  |    +- (8, 7, 'window', 'Windshield')
  |    +- (9, 7, 'window', 'Rear Window')
  |    +- (10, 7, 'window', 'Driver Front Window')
  |    +- (11, 7, 'window', 'Passenger Front Window')
  |    +- (12, 7, 'window', 'Driver Rear Window')
  |    +- (13, 7, 'window', 'Passenger Rear Window')
  +- (14, 1, 'mirrors', 'Mirrors')
       +- (15, 14, 'mirror', 'Rearview Mirror')
       +- (16, 14, 'mirror', 'Driver Mirror')
       +- (17, 14, 'mirror', 'Passenger Mirror')
```

Now then, the hard part: copying the tree. Because of the `parent_id` references we can't do something like an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`; we're reduced to having to use a recursive function. I know, we're entering The Dirty place. I'm going to pseudo-code this since you didn't note which language you're working with.

```
FUNCTION copyTreeByID (INTEGER id, INTEGER max_depth = 10, INTEGER parent_id = 0)
    row = MYSQL_QUERY_ROW ("SELECT * FROM tree WHERE id=?", id)
    IF NOT row
    THEN
        RETURN NULL
    END IF

    IF ! MYSQL_QUERY ("INSERT INTO trees (parent_id, type, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", parent_id, row["type"], row["name"])
    THEN
        RETURN NULL
    END IF
    parent_id = MYSQL_LAST_INSERT_ID ()

    IF max_depth LESSTHAN 0
    THEN
        RETURN
    END IF

    rows = MYSQL_QUERY_ROWS ("SELECT id FROM trees WHERE parent_id=?", id)
    FOR rows AS row
        copyTreeByID (row["id"], max_depth - 1, parent_id)
    END FOR

    RETURN parent_id
END FUNCTION

FUNCTION copyTreeByTypeName (STRING type, STRING name)
    row = MYSQL_QUERY_ROW ("SELECT id FROM tree WHERE parent_id=0 AND type=? AND name=?", type, name)
    IF NOT ARRAY_LENGTH (row)
    THEN
        RETURN
    END IF
    RETURN copyTreeByID (row["id"])
END FUNCTION
```

`copyTreeByTypeName` looks up the tree ID for the matching `type` and `name` and passes it to `copyTreeByID`. This is mostly a utility function to help you copy stuff by type/name.

`copyTreeByID` is the real beast. Fear it because it is recursive and evil. Why is it recursive? Because your trees are not predictable and can be any depth. But it's okay, we've got a variable to track depth and limit it (`max_depth`). So let's walk through it.

Start by grabbing all the data for the element. If we didn't get any data, just return. Re-insert the data with the element's `type` and `name`, and the passed `parent_id`. If the query fails, return. Set the `parent_id` to the last insert ID so we can pass it along later. Check for `max_depth` being less than zero, which indicates we've reached max depth; if we have return. Grab all the elements from the tree that have a parent of `id`. Then for each of those elements recurse into `copyTreeByID` passing the element's `id`, `max_depth` minus 1, and the new `parent_id`. At the end return `parent_id` so you can access the new copy of the elements.

Make sense? (I read it back and it made sense, not that that means anything).

Comment: Yep, that makes sense, I appreciate the detailed answer. I'll be adding children from different tables, however that answer would work for different tables as well with a bit of modification, for example:
("SELECT id FROM trees WHERE parent_id=?
UNION
SELECT id FROM other_table WHERE parent_id=?", id, id)

Comment: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNSIGNED"` :: does not work in postgres. Nice try, though ...

Comment: I never said it would in Postgres, then again, I didn't explicitly say it was for MySQL. Still, the pseudo-code mentions MySQL repeatedly...